# How to use absolute coords in pixijs

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

My question is about moving lines and rects using absolute coords.

1. I created line:

```
const line = new PIXI.Graphics();
line.lineStyle(2, 0xffffff);
line.moveTo(100, 200);
line.lineTo(300, 200);
app.stage.addChild(line);
```

But if I will try to set coords by changing x/y it will be relative to created pos:

```
line.x = 200; // real x will be 300
line.y = 200; // real y will be 400
```

How should I move this line if i need to set absolute coords on view?
Should I always calc absolute coords using current?

2. Same question about rect, I create it like this:

```
const blueBox = new PIXI.Graphics();
blueBox.beginFill(0x0000ff);
blueBox.drawRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
blueBox.endFill();
app.stage.addChild(blueBox);
```

If i will try to move it using x/y i will do same as line - x/y are relative, ok.
I can always draw rects at 0/0 point and then move them, but is it correct desigin, is there other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule you shouldn't trigger redraws on Graphics objects if they don't change visually. It's a computationally expensive operation, and merely repositioning the object doesn't justify calling it.

A better alternative is painting the line or rect using local coordinates and placing it at the target absolute position by setting the `position` property. I prefer to keep `(0, 0)` as the center of the shape, but choosing the top-left corner or any other point of reference is also valid. For a rectangle it would look like this:

```js
const blueBox = new PIXI.Graphics();
blueBox.beginFill(0x0000ff);
blueBox.drawRect(-25, -25, 50, 50);
blueBox.endFill();
blueBox.position.set(25, 25);
app.stage.addChild(blueBox);
```

From this point, all changes to the absolute position of the rectangle should happen by changing the position property, not by redrawing the graphics with the new coordinates.

Comment: so start point is setting when Graphics is creating, thanks

Comment: That's one way to say it. All created objects start at `(0, 0)`, and the graphics are drawn in the local coordinate system. Please consider accepting the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Yes, just that we can draw object at any pos and move it only relative to it - confused me, I thought there should be way to use both relative and absolute coords.

Comment: Once that blueBox has been added to the hierarchy you can also get its absolute position by calling `blueBox.toGlobal()` https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.DisplayObject.html#toGlobal . Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Nope, just how to set global position, you already answered my question, thx again